# Exception handling for Spring Boot @Async methods

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I'm pretty new to Spring Boot. In a project I'd like to send an email asyncronously. Below, you can see what I have so far.

A problem I have is the following: An external system sends a POST request to the controller. If some exception occurs while building or sending the mail, then the `GlobalExceptionHandler` does not get called. As a consequence, the controller always returns an HTTP 201, so the caller assumes that everything went fine.

How would I integrate my exception handlers with `@ControllerAdvice` in such async methods?

**Controller**

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/mail", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void send(@Validated @RequestBody EmailNotificationRequest emailNotificationRequest) throws MessagingException {
    emailService.sendMessage(emailNotificationRequest);
}
```

**Service**

```java
@Async
public void sendMessage(EmailNotificationRequest emailNotificationRequest) throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

    // build the message

    javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

**ExceptionHandler**

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends AbstractExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * Handles any exception which is not handled by a specific {@link ExceptionHandler}.
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Throwable.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ApplicationResponse handleThrowable(Throwable ex) {
        log.error("An unhandled error occurred: {}", ex.getMessage());
        return buildErrorResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this article offers some help https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Async will not call by @ControllerAdvice for global exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885358/async-will-not-call-by-controlleradvice-for-global-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about moving the `@Async` into a lower level, so only the

`javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);`

Will be called in an async way?

Extract it to a different bean with a public async method that wraps the `javaMailSender` and remove the Async from the mothod of `sendMessage`